# Passport + JWT + Socket.IO Authentication

Tags: node.js, socket.io, passport.js, jwt, koa

I'm looking for the best direction on implementing JWT Authentication with Socket.io in my KOA NodeJS application.

I found a great [repo](https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt) on socketio + jwt but the author does not use passport nor koa.  I think I've got a good start but I'm wondering if Passport is overkill at this point since I'm using JWT. Below is my code.

**Koa.js**

```js
import koa from 'koa';
import router from 'koa-router';

import json from 'koa-json';
import bodyParser from 'koa-bodyparser';

import passport from './passport';
import session from './session';
import { config } from './env/env';

export class Koa {

  constructor(){
    this.app = koa();
    this.initMiddleware();
  }

  initMiddleware(){
    this.app.use(json());
    this.app.use(bodyParser());

    this.app.keys = config.secret;
    this.app.use(session);
    this.app.use(passport.initialize());
    this.app.use(passport.session());
  }

}
```

**Session.js**

```js
import session from 'koa-generic-session';

// todo: configure for db backed store
export default session();
```

**Passport.js**

```js
import passport from 'koa-passport';
import { config } from './env/env';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';

// todo!
var user = { id: 1, username: 'test' }

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id)
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  done(null, user)
});

const opts = {
  secretOrKey: config.secret
};

passport.use(new Strategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
  // User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, function(err, user) {
  if (username === 'test' && password === 'test') {
    done(null, user)
  } else {
    done(null, false)
  }
}));

export default passport;
```

**socketio.js**

```js
import io from 'socket.io';
import session from './session';

export class SocketIO {

  constructor(application){
    this.io = io(application.server);

    // authenticate middleware
    this.io.use(function(socket, next){
      // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095418/how-to-use-passport-with-express-and-socket-io
      // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643370/get-user-id-socket-io-passport-koa
      //var sid = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie)['koa.sid'];
      session.apply(socket.request, next);
    });

    this.buildEvents();
  }

  buildEvents(){
    this.io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log(`new connection: ${socket.id}`);

      // accessible through a api route
      application.app.socket = socket;

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`disconnected: ${socket.id}`);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may be right in that passport may be overkill. Maybe check out [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) on npm?

Then you can add the `.verify()` function to your authenticating middleware, and just use .sign() when creating your session in order to designate a user as authenticated.

Comment: I plan to add OAuth eventually to my app so thats the only reason why I'm still on the fence.